# Function header comments in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

How to generate these kind of function header comments in Netbeans? Is the any shortcut that would give a template along with the parameter names?

```
/**
* Performs the Decrease Key operation
* @param index Index of the node in the RefArray whose key is to be decreased
* @param amount Amount by which key is to be reduced
*/
public void decreaseKey(int index, int amount)
{
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just above the method, constructor or field, type `/**` and follow by pressing enter key immediately. Netbeans should generate template for javadoc.

Comment: By the way, Is there a way to get netbeans to do this for the whole file?

Comment: @user3885927: You can make a right click on the File (or package or project), select "Tools" - "Analyze Javadoc" and select then all items which you will fix (in the "Analyzer" view) and click on "Fix Selected". See also at http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/05/automatically-generate-javadoc-skeleton.html